# Как в тексте найти и заменить ссылками все 6-значные цифры?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Добрый день. Никогда не дружил с регулярными выражениями, нужно в тексте найти все 6-значные цифры и заменить их ссылками. Спасибо за внимание!

Например, текст:

```
258945 - **это нужно заменить ссылкой <a href="mysite.ru">258945</a>**
258963 - **это нужно заменить ссылкой <a href="mysite.ru">258963</a>**
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/\d{6}/g
```

Comment: Скорее `/(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)/`, чтобы семизначные не ловились.